# uploading files into sftp share generates empty files

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, fstab

I have successfuly mounted an sftp share on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop into the location: **/mnt/sftp/**

I am facing an unexplained behavior:

- When uploading file using software like Filezilla, everything works fine.
- When using fstab to mount the sftp share into /mnt/sftp/ and then copying any file into it via **cp** command, I get the following error:

> '/tmp/file_test' -> '/mnt/sftp/file_test'
> cp: impossible de créer
> lefichier standard '/mnt/sftp/file_test': Aucun fichier ou dossier de
> ce type

Which translates to:

> cp: cannot create standard file '/mnt/sftp/file_test':
> No such file or directory

The file is present but totaly empty.The fact that Filezilla works fine means it is not a permission issue.

The corresponding fstab entry looks like this:

```
obfuscated_username@obfuscated_servername:/ /mnt/sftp fuse.sshfs _netdev,port=7000,idmap=user,allow_other,reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=60 0 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the filezilla and local user the same?

Comment: It is not local user. The username was provided by the hosting company.